# Use RegEx to search pattern, exclude another

Tags: regex

I'm using Regex to include all patterns except one.

My code so far:

```
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk('z:/rod/folder'):
    for name in files:
        currentfile=os.path.join(root,name)
        with open(currentfile) as d:
            text = d.read()
            regex = re.compile('2\sFF\s{28}\d\sLOANS')
            a = regex.findall(text)
            if a:
                with open('z:/rod/results.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(os.path.join(root,name))
                    f.write('\n')
```

This code will include all files where '2 FF                           (any number) LOANS' which is OK, but I do not want any files that has a zero in the string - for example:
'2 FF                           0 LOANS'

If the files has any other number in the string, such as,  '2 FF                           75 LOANS' - this is OK.  But I do not want '2 FF                           0 LOANS'.

Does this make sense?  please help me finish the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
2\sFF\s(?!0 )\d+\sLOANS
```

`\s(?!0 )` will only match the space if its not followed by a zero and a space. With this regex strings with multiple zeros *will* be matched. For example `2 FF 0000 LOANS` will be matched.

If you do not want this you can use this:

```
2\sFF\s(?!0+ )\d+\sLOANS
```